# Automating the clicking of "Yes"

Tags: vbscript

I've searched the site but not knowing what I'm looking for makes it hard to find the answer.

What I need to do is this:

I have a file that runs for my weather station.  When it is opened it brings up a dialogue box which requires "Yes" to be clicked.  Following this another box opens which also requires "Yes" to be clicked.

I want to make this process automatic so that when I open the main file, the two dialogue box "Yes" buttons are "pressed" automatically.

Lets say the main program name is "weather"
The first dialogue box is called "station"
The second dialogue box is called "wind"

Thanks in advance and sorry if this has been answered before.

Jim

Comment: `vbscript` doesn't play particularly well with dialog objects.  What kind of file are you opening?

Comment: It's an exe file that runs my weather station recording software.  There's nothing particularly odd about it except that it asks for confirmation of the type of station and wind recorder.  The dialogue boxes just come up and say : Station type xxxx detected : continue yes / no and then anemometer type yyy detected : continue yes / no.  I just need to click yes both times.  The problem is that the software has no facility to remember the answer.  So every time the computer gets reset (it's normally on all the time), the software stall until I get to click the buttons..  I guessed VB might help.

Comment: You could write some `vbscript` to detect the application is running, and use `SendKeys` for example to be able to send keystrokes (such as an `Enter` or a `Y` to it) to cope with the dialog.

Comment: I agree with @Dave. It does not play well and is possible to overcome with his suggestions. I have also found that auto hot key (https://autohotkey.com/) is useful for these situations since they have some syntax and commands in there to help you switch windows, move the mouse to either a position relative to the application or screen, and then send a click for example.